# PHP Arrays Selection from URL

Tags: php, arrays, url

I have coded a internal messenger system for the company I work for and I am trying to make things easier for myself by making a admin panel for this so it can control the usernames, passwords and groups.

Basically I am trying to select a user from the array using a url `?user=username` which will then return the user information and allow it to be changed. The problem I am having is to get the url to select the username in the array.

The array is basic:

```
$users = array(
    '0' => array(
        'username' => 'test',
        'password' => 'test123',
        'group' => 'office',
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?:

```
<?php

// get username from URL (GET METHOD)
$username=$_GET["username"];

// $users has all the info

foreach ($users as $u) {
  // find the target user
  if ($u["username"] == $username) {
      // do something with $u
      var_dump($u);
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I would guess I can do the same to get the password and group?

Comment: Yes, in this code, $u has all the information about the user. (check it). $u["password"] has the password, $u["group"] has the group.

Comment: Ok thank you =D @verjas , I just have to find a way to allow it to change the information in to that array without changing any of the others.

Comment: You should use a login system, so only authorized users have access to the data. Then, use a HTML form to input data like change password (or group, or whatever). Then use a php file to process the form to change the database... It's more work than this simple code :)

Comment: Yes I did debate weather to use a login system but because of the use for the system this way is easier as the array is holding the passwords which no one apart from me and the other it person can access no one else can view it or change. I just wanted to build something to make it easier for me to change the passwords rather than keep navigating on the server to find the file all the time.

Comment: would you know if i can use a form to input the changes to the array? and how would this be possible without changing the whole array? would I just use php to find the specific point and tell it change? Im a bit unsure with arrays. I should have used a mysql database as this would of been easier.

Comment: If you don't use a database, how is the data stored? In a file, I guess, but what is it: json, txt, csv, serialized array? Of course you can use a form to change just one part of the data :) You just need a php file to process the form and change specific data. [about the login system, if you don't use it, you better make sure nobody can access those links ]

Comment: The chat system itself is just a php file included in to the admin.php I am currently trying to build. The file itself is going to be passworded using php.

I have some code but is not working, Might be something I have done wrong.

Comment: $_POST[] = array(
        'users'=>array(
            'username'=>'value',
            'password'=>'value',
            'group'=>'value'
        ),
    )

<form action="" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="users[username]" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"><br />
Password: <input type="text" name="users[password]" value="<?php echo $password; ?>"><br />
Group: <input type="text" name="users[group]" value="<?php echo $group; ?>"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Changes">
    </form>

Comment: Ok thank you =D I am new to joining this board so unsure how to do this.

Comment: me neither...(can't find the button) just skype: pax.liviu

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to do this:

```
$user_name = $users[0]["username"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an array i assume you have multiple indexes. I guess a simple 'find' function might work.

```
function findUser($searchData, $users, $searchField) {
    $retObj = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if (isset($user[$searchField]) && $user[$searchField] == $searchData) {
            $retObj['username'] = $user['username'];
            $retObj['password'] = $user['password'];
            $retObj['group'] = $user['group'];
            break;
        }
    }
    return $retObj;
}
```

EDIT: Added searchField so u can do same for password and group. Searchdata is the value u are searching

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested)

```
$u = null;
foreach($user as $user) {
    if(isset($_GET['user']) && $user['username'] == $_GET['user']) {
        $u = $user;
    }
}
```

$u variable should contains yours user record.